# Fetching user account additional field in views global php

Tags: views

I want to fetch the additional account field by using `global php` in `Views`.
The additional account is shown below:

[image]

The code I use in `Global PHP` output:

```
<?php 
global $user;
$namepsm = strtoupper(str_replace("_"," ",$row->value));
print ($namepsm .  ' ' . $user->field_id_number) ;
?>
```

I have an error

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_id_number in __lambda_func() (line 4

I can use other standard account fields, for example `$user->name` or `$user->$mail`.

How can I **print** the additional account field (field_id_number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `user_load` function to load your account, like so:

```
$logged_in_user = user_load($user->uid);
```

Then `dpm($logged_in_user)` or `print_r($logged_in_user)` you will see you have access to the field you added.

Comment: Thanks I can see that. Now it works, I add `$logged_in_user = user_load($user->uid);` and the 4th line replaced by this `print ($namepsm .  ' ' . $logged_in_user->field_id_number['und'][0]['value']) ;`